# How to search two fields in a table with VB

Tags: vba, ms-access

This code was not written by me, a Friend who is no longer with us, who had a better knowledge of VB wrote it for me back in 2000. It takes an input and decides whether it is a customers name, postcode, phone number or mobile number. Now with the proliferation of mobile numbers I need to add a second field for a second mobile number. I have a spare field called C_FAX which I can use, so I need to be able to search twice when a mobile number is inputted C_MOBILE and C_FAX, I did just duplicate the DoCmd for mobile and changed the search field to C_FAX which did sort of work and i was able to find a mobile number in the C_FAX field but did not find it in the C_MOBILE field. any suggestions would be gratefully received. Many Thanks Neil

```
Private Sub SearchText_AfterUpdate()
PhoneSearch = PhoneFix(Me!SearchText)
If Me![SearchText] Like "*[A-Z]#*" Then
' postcode
DoCmd.OpenForm "custom1", , , "[C_POSTCODE] like('" & Me![SearchText] & "*')"

ElseIf InStr(PhoneSearch, "07") = 1 Then
'mobile
DoCmd.OpenForm "custom1", , , "[C_MOBILE] like('" & PhoneSearch & "*')"

ElseIf InStr(PhoneSearch, "0") = 1 Then
'phone
DoCmd.OpenForm "custom1", , , "[C_PHONE] like('" & PhoneSearch & "*')"

ElseIf Me![SearchText] Like "2*" Then
' cust_code
DoCmd.OpenForm "custom1", , , "[CUST_CODE] like('" & Me![SearchText] & "*')"

ElseIf Not IsNull(Me![SearchText]) Then
'name
DoCmd.OpenForm "custom1", , , "[C_NAME] like('*" & Me![SearchText] & "*')"

End If

Forms!entry!Comment = " "
Me.Requery
Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this Access?, if so please use Access tag.

Comment: Yes it is Visual basic within Access. Well spotted, I will Thanks Neil

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an [OR statement](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/or_vba.php) to the code to read the new 2nd field for additional mobiles. For example purposes lets call this field SearchText2 and your variable PhoneSearch2:

```
PhoneSearch2 = PhoneFix(Me!SearchText2)

ElseIf InStr(PhoneSearch, "07") = 1 Or InStr(PhoneSearch2, "07") = 1 Then 

' do your thing
```

Comment: thanks you certainly pointed me in the right answer, this is how it actually looked like                                                                                 DoCmd.OpenForm "custom1", , , "[C_MOBILE] like('" & PhoneSearch & "*')or[C_FAX] like('" & PhoneSearch & "*')"